# bossfight mini game. how to keep lowering boss health until 0

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

I'm trying to let the user select the class they want. Either a warrior or rogue. Each warrior attack will have 10% increased damage and each rogue attack has a 10% chance to double. My code works and repeats as i thought, but i cant figure out how to let it keep the healthleft after attacking the boss. I want the boss to lose health each time the user presses 1 until boss =0. I've tried everything i can think of using while and for loops. Am i doing this completely wrong?

```
import random




Boss = 1000

def war_attack():
    rand =  random.randrange(2,102, 2)
    warratk = rand + rand * .10
    healthleft = Boss - warratk
    print("You did", warratk, "damage!")
    print(healthleft)



def rogue_attack():
    rand = random.randrange(2,102, 2)   
    a = random.randrange(1,11)
    if a == 4:
        rogueattk = rand + rand
    else:
        rogueattk = rand
    healthleft = Boss - rogueattk
    print("You did", rogueattk, "damage!")
    print("Boss Health Remaining : ", healthleft)    

print("") 
print("Please choose a class. Warrior or Rogue.")
print("-Warriors have 10% increased strength.")
print("-Rogues have a 10% chance for critical damage.")

Class = str(input("Enter your class: "))



while Boss >= 0:
    attack = int(input("Enter '1' to attack: "))

    if Class == "Warrior" or Class == "warrior":
        war_attack()
    elif Class == "Rogue" or Class == "rogue":
        rogue_attack()
```

Comment: On a more offtopic note: you really should use a different variable name as `Class`. Technically python is case sensitive but it's generally a good practice to avoid variable names identical to keywords.

Comment: thankyou for your input. will change in future